# how to change the data type in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables question and question_paper . in question_paper i have a column named question_ids .in question_ids-(text type) i stored the question table's id like 2,5,23,45,6,9 etc.  now the problem is when i trying to fetch the data using

`select * from question where id IN (select question_ids from question where id=1)`  it passes the question_ids as a string type so it returns only first matched id's value.so, i need to change this query result as a number type is it possible in mysql or is there any function using i can change the type temporary.thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried CAST() or CONVERT()?  Just google "mysql cast"

Comment: Try this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) to first split your question_id string into rows and then use that for your sub-query. I think that should work.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL `CAST()` function to convert a value of any type into a value with a specified type.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/

Comment: I tried but not working i am confused with subquery how to use CAST() with subquery . is this right way  "select * from question where id IN (CAST((select question_ids from question where id=1) AS UNSIGNED ))"

Comment: is there any another way like i can remove the '' quotes from the  result of subquery.

Comment: in your question_id have commas so how it is possible to cast in UNSIGNED?

Comment: yeah agree but i need something that can change the subquery result from string to number.

Comment: You should split question_ids and use in the subquery

Comment: ya i did this for temporary if i got the solution i ll update.Thanks to all of you.